# ie position relative bug

Tags: jquery, css

The following code works in firefox and chrome, but in ie the div that I am trying to make appear in a certain spot doesn't appear at all.  It works the same way in all 3 browsers when position is absolute, but I need position to be relative here.  Anyone know the problem?

```
$('#main-chat').addClass('shrink').attr('id', '').appendTo('#other-chats' + otherChats).
    css({
        'height':'100%',
        'width':'100%',
        'position':'relative',
        'left': '-30px'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you position a div absolutely, it would not take into consideration the relative divs beside it.
Incase you are using relative, make sure that you are closing any left off div tags which must be closed. IE has a stricter approach towards html.